# How to vectorize expanding a compressed sparse matrix from vector of column indices?

Tags: r, vector, vectorization, sparse-matrix, indices

I want to build a matrix from a vector as follow: if the first element of y is 5, I want to make the first row and 5th column of matrix 1. others in the row are 0.

```
y=round(runif(30)*9)+1
y_m=matrix(rep(0,length(y)*10),ncol=10)
for (i in 1:length(y)){
  y_m[i,y[i]]=1;
}
```

Is there any way to avoid the for loop? I was trying to do `y_m[,y]=1` but apparently it is not working.

Comment: I think you mean *"expand a compressed sparse matrix from vector of column indices"*

Comment: A different approach: `xtabs(rep(1, length(y)) ~ seq_along(y) + y)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: use a two-column index matrix.  From `?"["`:

> When indexing arrays by ‘[’ a single argument ‘i’ can be a
>             matrix with as many columns as there are dimensions of ‘x’;
>             the result is then a vector with elements corresponding to
>             the sets of indices in each row of ‘i’.

Setup:

```
set.seed(101)
y <- round(runif(30)*9)+1
```

Your way (I streamlined the matrix construction a bit):

```
y_m <- matrix(0,ncol=10,nrow=length(y))
for (i in 1:length(y)){
  y_m[i,y[i]] <- 1
}
```

Via matrix indexing:

```
y_m2 <- matrix(0,ncol=10,nrow=length(y))
y_m2[cbind(1:length(y),y)] <- 1
```

Check:

```
all.equal(y_m,y_m2)  ## TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use:

```
y_m[cbind(1:length(y), y)] <- 1
```

---

Since you have a sparse matrix, you may want:

```
sparse_y_m <- Matrix::sparseMatrix(i = 1:length(y), j = y, x = 1)
```

In case you want a full matrix, use

```
y_m <- as.matrix(sparse_y_m)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xtabs` to make your matrix from only `y`, spreading a vector of 1s by an index of row numbers, i.e. `seq_along(y)` and then `y` itself:

```
xtabs(rep(1, length(y)) ~ seq_along(y) + y)
##             y
## seq_along(y) 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
##           1  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0
##           2  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
##           3  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
##           4  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0
##           5  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0
##           6  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0
##           ...
```

or make it a sparse matrix:

```
xtabs(rep(1, length(y)) ~ seq_along(y) + y, sparse = TRUE)
## 30 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
##                       
## 1  . . . 1 . . . . . .
## 2  . 1 . . . . . . . .
## 3  1 . . . . . . . . .
## 4  . . . . . . 1 . . .
## 5  . . . 1 . . . . . .
## 6  . . . 1 . . . . . .
## ...
```

or set it up with a data.frame to get better labels:

```
xtabs(i ~ row + y, data.frame(y, i = 1, row = seq_along(y)))
##     y
## row  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
##   1  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0
##   2  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
##   3  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
##   4  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0
##   5  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0
##   6  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0
##   ...
```

Comment: I tried, `data.matrix` `model.matrix`, so fairly close ... Thanks!!